# How can I convert this code into HTML only?

Tags: html, css

how can I convert this HTML+CSS code into HTML only?
I'm trying to use this in an email, so the CSS won't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

  <style>
  #u168 { z-index: 34; background-color: #57E8E8; padding-bottom: 7px; position: relative; margin-right: -10000px; margin-top: 345px; width: 48.58%; left: 27.15%; } #u186-5 { z-index: 37; min-height: 23px; background-color: transparent; color: #131E2E; font-size: 18px; line-height: 22px; position: relative; margin-right: -10000px; margin-top: 6px; width: 92.06%; left: 2.65%; } #u174 { z-index: 35; background-color: #57E8E8; padding-bottom: 8px; position: relative; margin-right: -10000px; margin-top: 384px; width: 48.58%; left: 27.15%; }  #u186-2,#u189-2 { font-weight: bold; } #u177 { z-index: 36; background-color: #57E8E8; padding-bottom: 8px; position: relative; margin-right: -10000px; margin-top: 423px; width: 48.58%; left: 27.15%; } 

  </style>
   </head>
 <body>
<div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u168"><!-- group -->
      <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u186-5"><!-- content -->
       <p>User: <span id="u186-2">test</span></p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u174"><!-- group -->
      <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u189-5"><!-- content -->
       <p>Password: <span id="u189-2">test</span></p>
      </div>
     </div>
</html>
```

Comment: It is HTML...not sure what you are asking.

Comment: If you mean the CSS classes for the HTML elements, you could use inline CSS instead, like `style="selector:value;"`

Comment: For emails, you should have both the `style` tag as well as inline styles as Chris mentioned ^. Some clients only use the inline while others only use `style` tags.. it's wildly annoying but welcome to emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use inline CSS instead of internal CSS**

```
<div style="z-index: 34; background-color: #57E8E8; padding-bottom: 7px; position: relative; margin-right: -10000px; margin-top: 345px; width: 48.58%; left: 27.15%;">
   <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what I was looking for. Idk why I got so much backlash :(

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean using inline style? You can write them directly as style="z-index:1,..." and remove the id attributes from the divs.